# Batch-wise norm of a tensor

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor *t* of dim `n x 3`. When I apply `torch.linalg.norm` it returns one single value. What I need is a batch-wise norm function which will return a tensor with *n* norms, one for each vector in *t*.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would recommend changing the title to be pytorch specific and perhaps including the (`torch.linalg.norm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the most relevant documentation place is:
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.norm.html

In the terminal you could try: `python3` and then the following python commands:

```
>>> from torch import linalg as LA
>>> c = torch.tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
...                   [-1, 1, 4]])
>>> LA.norm(c, dim=0)
tensor([1.4142, 2.2361, 5.0000])
>>> LA.norm(c, dim=1)
tensor([3.7417, 4.2426])
```

**Conclusion:**
In your specific case you will need to do:

```
torch.linalg.norm(t,dim=1)
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks. Instead of torch.linalg.norm(t,dim=1), I just tried torch.linalg.norm(t,1), which I thought would work as well.